# Optimal dependency of HHL (or any QLSP) algorithm on condition number $\kappa$

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra, complexity-theory, hhl-algorithm, bqp

This is conserning the optimal dependency on condition number for Quantum linear system problem (QLSP).

For solving QLSP, the HHL (algorithm) paper mentions any **polylog($\kappa$)** quantum algorihm would imply $BPP=PSPACE$. This means polylog($\kappa$) quantum algorithm is extremely unlikely. See page-3; paragraph 2 on the right side; [Link](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.150502).

I went through an improved algorithm by Child-Kothari-Somma (CKS). Which mentions any sublinear algorithm in $\kappa$ is unlikely. OR, linear dependency on $\kappa$ is optimal. See page-4; last paragraph; [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02306.pdf). It cites HHL paper as reference.

I find CKS's statemnet quite stronger. Because, $\kappa^{1/2}$ dependency is also ***sublinear***, thus excluded.

My query is:

> What is the best known lower bound on condition number?

> How to make sense of $\Omega(\kappa)$ mentioned in CKS paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best known lower bound on condition number?

Costa et. la.<sup>[[1](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2111.08152)]</sup> use the discrete adiabatic theorem to develop a quantum algorithm for solving linear systems with complexity strictly linear in $\kappa$, matching the lower bound.

> How to make sense of $\Omega(\kappa)$ mentioned in CKS paper?

CKS paper refers to HHL as the source of this fact. Actually, you can find it just after excluding the possibility of $\mathrm{polylog}(\kappa)$ quantum algorithm,

> "Even improving our $\kappa$ dependence to $\kappa^{1 - \delta}$ for $\delta \gt 0$ would allow any time-$T$ quantum algorithm to be simulated in time $o(T)$; iterating this would again imply that $\mathrm{BQP}=\mathrm{PSPACE}$."